# Are JobListeners global in a Quartz cluster?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, listener, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler

I'm running a clustered instance of Quartz in the context of a Java EE application. One of the nodes (selected randomly) in the Java EE application will fire a series of Quartz jobs to be executed immediately (as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890212/java-quartz-scheduler-fire-a-new-job-immediately])); right before triggering each job, a JobListener associated to that job is added to the scheduler's ListenerManager.

If I understand Quartz's inner working correctly, the node that actually executes each job will be [selected at random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847543/execution-of-jobs-in-a-quartz-cluster) from the available nodes. If that's the case, how can the listener's methods be called if the listener was created in a node different from the one that executed the job? Can I assume that the list of listeners in ListenerManager is global and the same for all the nodes in the cluster? Or each node has its own ListManager with its own listeners?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question?

Comment: @ccleve no, and in the end we didn't use Quartz in cluster

Comment: Did you implement a clustered solution using something other than Quartz?

Comment: @ccleve no, we simply didn't use a cluster. Our experiments showed that the listeners in Quartz are _not_ cluster-aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Quartz documentation:

> Listeners are registered with the scheduler during run time, and are
>   NOT stored in the JobStore along with the jobs and triggers. This is
>   because listeners are typically an integration point with your
>   application. Hence, each time your application runs, the listeners
>   need to be re-registered with the scheduler.

Refer to http://quartz-scheduler.org/files/documentation/Quartz-2.1.x-Documentation.pdf

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I found some more useful information in a [free, online book](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.65.1/quartz_clustering_cookbook.html):

> Using Global Listeners in a Clustered Environment
>
> You can still use job and trigger listeners in a clustered
>   environment. The only confusion comes in when you try to understand
>   which Scheduler instance will receive the callback method.
>
> The easiest way to remember this is that the Listener will be notified
>   in the Scheduler instance where the job or trigger is executed.
>   Because a job and trigger are executed on only a single node, the
>   Listener is notified on that node.