# Get running jobs in clustered Quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler

How do I find out whether a particular job is currently running in Quartz when Quartz is clustered?

The standard answer to the "get running jobs" question is to use `scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();` But according to the javadoc, this doesn't work in a clustered environment.

Another answer is to use a JobListener and just store the status of the job somewhere when it starts and stops. But according to this, JobListeners do not work in a clustered environment:

[Are JobListeners global in a Quartz cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631099/are-joblisteners-global-in-a-quartz-cluster)

So what's the trick?

Answer (score 1):

No way except querying Quartz table `qrtz_fired_triggers` directly.